# Network image as Marker for google_maps_flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to use Network image as marker for the [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter). It keeps on showing me the default pin holder instead.

```
var markerbitmap;

getpicture() async {
    String imgurl =
    "http://domain/image.jpg";
    Uint8List bytes = (await NetworkAssetBundle(Uri.parse(imgurl)).load(imgurl))
    .buffer
    .asUint8List();
    setState(() {
        markerbitmap = BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(bytes);
    });
}

@override
void initState() {
    getpicture();
}

_addMarker(LatLng position, String id, BitmapDescriptor descriptor) {
    MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(id);
    Marker marker =
    Marker(markerId: markerId, icon: descriptor, position: position);
    _markers[markerId] = marker;
}

void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
    LatLng latLng_1 = LatLng(startCoordinatesLat, startCoordinatesLng);
    LatLng latLng_2 = LatLng(endCoordinatesLat, endCoordinatesLng);
    _markers.clear();
    _addMarker(
        latLng_1,
        "origin",
        markerbitmap ?? BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
    );
    _addMarker(
        latLng_2,
        "destination",
        markerbitmap ?? BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
    );
    _addMarker(
        LatLng(31.5096673920523, 74.37318230126559),
        "waypoint",
        markerbitmap ?? BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
    );
    setState(() {
    });
}

GoogleMap(
    onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
    initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
    mapType: MapType.normal,
    tiltGesturesEnabled: true,
    compassEnabled: true,
    scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
    zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
    polylines: Set < Polyline >.of(_polylines.values),
    markers: Set < Marker >.of(_markers.values),
    onCameraMove: _onCameraMove,
    myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that `getpicture()` is an async function, and you call it in `initState`, but the `build` method where you create `GoogleMap` widget will run **before this future completes**.

Even if you call `setState` after `getpicture()` fetches the network image, the `GoogleMap` widget will not be rebuilt because the variable `markerbitmap` is not used directly when building your widget: it is used only in `_onMapCreated` function, which runs once `GoogleMap` is created.

So this is what happens:

1. `initState` called
2. `getpicture` starts
3. `build` method is called
4. `GoogleMap` widget is built
5. `_onMapCreated` is called
6. `markerbitmap` is still empty so default marker is used
7. ... (async gap)
8. after some time `getpicture` is finished and `markerbitmap` is set but the widget is already built.

I would try to use a `FutureBuilder` to get the network image and build `GoogleMap` only when it is completed.

Transform `getpicture` to future function:

```
Future <Uint8List>getpicture() async {
  String imgurl = "http://domain/image.jpg";
  Uint8List bytes = (await NetworkAssetBundle(Uri.parse(imgurl)).load(imgurl))
    .buffer
    .asUint8List();
    
  return bytes;
}
```

Create a state class member for the future and assign a value to it in `initState`:

```
late final Future <Uint8List> _getPictureFuture;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _getPictureFuture = getpicture();
}
```

Use the future function in a `FutureBuilder`:

```
FutureBuilder<Uint8List>(
  future: _getPictureFuture,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      // here you have the data from the completed future
      markerbitmap = BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(snapshot.data!);
      
      return GoogleMap(...);            
    }
    else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      // handle error
    }
    // display progress indicator
    return const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator());
  });
)
```